# Get the name of a boost message_queue

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue

When I create a boost message queue, in the constructor I pass the name:

```
using boost::interprocess;

//Create a message_queue.
message_queue mq
             (create_only               //only create
             ,"message_queue"           //name
             ,100                       //max message number
             ,sizeof(int)               //max message size
             );
```

This name is also used in the remove method, to erase the queue from the system:

```
message_queue::remove("message_queue");
```

My question is: if I only have the message queue object, how can I get the name of the queue from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documented interface for that.

Even the shmem object implementation member `m_shmem` that receives the name on construction is private, so creating a subclass doesn't help to get access to it.

What's more the members of that that looked most promising appear not to have useful values (at least on my POSIX system):

- `bip::message_queue::m_shmem.get_device().get_mapping_handle().handle` reflects the value of -1
- `bip::message_queue::m_shmem.get_device().get_name()` reflect the empty string

I'd suggest simply creating your own type that manages the information you don't won't to repeat (which is a good idea, IYAM):

**<kbd>[<strike>Live¹</strike> On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ea580e5a9a0d9c3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

struct named_message_queue : bip::message_queue {
    template <typename Mode, typename... Args>
    explicit named_message_queue(Mode mode, const char *name, Args... args)
            : bip::message_queue(mode, name, args...), _name(name) {}

    std::string name() const { return _name; }

  private:
    std::string _name;
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    named_message_queue mq(bip::create_only, "message_queue", 100, sizeof(int));

    std::cout << "Name: " << mq.name() << "\n";
    mq.remove(mq.name().c_str());
}
```

Prints

```
Name: message_queue
```

---

¹ Coliru doesn't support shared memory